# Where did Hibiki learn to pilot the Vanguard

Tags: vandread

Hibiki Tokai was NEVER a pilot. He was a junior maintenance technician that entered the Ikazuchi on a dare.

Then he got the Pexis Vanguard, and became an ace pilot.

Where did he learn to pilot? Was it offscreen training, or the pexis implanted the knowledge of piloting in his mind, or another explanation?

Comment: he's a "newtype" :p

Comment: @кяαzєя his hair didn't go gold at the end.